# Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not be combined

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest

i synced my project, then i got those [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8ntO.png), my manifest code is:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "chtaibi.yahya.footballcards"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'

}
```

Can you help me please?

***** It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can migrate an existing project to [**`AndroidX`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) by selecting **`Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX`** from the menu bar.

> AndroidX replaces the original support library APIs with packages in
>   the androidx namespace. Only the package and Maven artifact names
>   changed; class, method, and field names did not change.

**Upgrade version**

```
compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {

        targetSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'


    }
```

Your **`dependencies`** will

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```